# Find basis of the following subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this exercise, can you please help me? I have all the solution, but I don't know how to work out! 
Thank you very much!

Consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$:
$$V:=L\{(0,1,-4,3),(-1,-3,0,4),(4,-4,6,-6),(4,3,-8,1)\}$$
$$W_\lambda:=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4:x_1+x_2+\lambda x_3+x_4=0\}$$
1) Calculate a basis of $V$

2) Calculate a basis of $V^\perp$

3) Calulate a base of $V\cap W_\lambda$

Comment: is $V$ spanned by the vectors in $L$?

Comment: $L(v_1,...,v_n)$ is the space generated by $v_1,...,v_n$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get a nice basis of $V$: begin with the matrix whose rows are the given vectors
$$
\pmatrix{
0&1&-4&3\\
-1&-3&0&4\\
4&-4&6&-6\\
4&3&-8&1
}
$$
row-reduce this matrix (that is, apply Gauss-Jordan elimination). The non-zero rows that remain form a basis of $V$.

Suppose that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ form a basis of $V$.  To find a basis of $V^\perp$, find a basis of the kernel (nullspace) of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
- & v_1 & -\\
- & v_2 & -\\
- & v_3 & -}
$$

Here's an approach to the last problem: define the matrices $A$ and $B$ by
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1&\lambda&1}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{
|&|&|\\
v_1&v_2&v_3\\
|&|&|
}
$$
If $\{u_1,u_2\}$ is a basis of the kernel of the matrix product $AB$, then $\{Bu_1,Bu_2\}$ is a basis of $V \cap W_\lambda$.

---

For the first question, we can row-reduce to get:
$$
\pmatrix{
0&1&-4&3\\
-1&-3&0&4\\
4&-4&6&-6\\
4&3&-8&1
} \to \cdots \to
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&1&-1\\
0&0&0&0
}
$$
Thus, $V$ has the basis $\{(1,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$

See the steps outlined below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I solve the given system? 'Cause i tried... but nothing

Comment: What do you mean? Which "given system" are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to find a basis for $W_\lambda$?

Comment: No, I'd like to know how to find a basis of $V$

Comment: Do you know what "row-reduction" or "Gauss-Jordan elimination" are?

Comment: Yeah, know... but by applying row-reduction it seems to be unuseful

Comment: I put up an answer explaining exactly why it is useful.  What leads you to believe otherwise?

Comment: because i want to find the basis but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Please comment in such a fashion that I don't have to guess what you mean.  What do you mean by "this"? Do you not know how to do row-reduction?  Do you not know how to follow any of the steps I describe?  Perhaps my approach is very dissimilar to your textbook's approach, so you don't know why it works.  All of those are excellent misunderstandings to have and overcome.  However, the first step (if you want help) is to **explain** what it is that you don't know how to do.

Comment: I want to know the steps to find the basis of th given subspace $V$

Comment: This explanation is insufficient. I've given you steps, what's wrong with those?

Comment: I don't know how you got the basis $\{(1,0,0,-1),(0,1,0,-1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$. How many passages you did? I'd like to have a step by step solution... if possible

Comment: See my edit  ${}{}$

Comment: wow! a bit hard! thanks